# What should I know before using "Patent Pending" in my products/ website?

Tags: software, law, patent-infringement, patent-pending, false-marking

Some years ago I read that you should not use the phrase "Patent Pending" in connection to products or marketing materials that do not actually feature **or describe** technology that is actually claimed in a pending patent application, as large fines can be applied.

Does this still stand? If I put a Patent Pending notice in a product do I have to describe it in the product? Can I just have a link to a description? What care do I need?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Does this still stand?

Yes. Deceptive use of 'patent pending' is an offense.

- More [here](http://www.uspto.gov/faq/patents.jsp#a1) from USPTO
- And more [here](http://www.ipo.gov.uk/types/patent/p-manage/p-useenforce/p-displayrights.htm) from UK IP Office

> If I put a Patent Pending notice in a product do I have to describe it in the product?

Not required. But you have to mention the patent application number and the country where the patent is applied for. UK information [here](http://www.ipo.gov.uk/types/patent/p-manage/p-useenforce/p-displayrights.htm).

> Can I just have a link to a description?

If you have already applied for a patent, yes you can have a webpage with a small description (use discretion).

> What care do I need?

After going through web-resources especially Patent Office websites you can seek professional advice if you have further queries or you just want to be that extra sure.